# Why were camera and display adapters not incorporated into official IO board?

Tags: display, raspicam, modules

Camera and display adapters have to be used with the official IO board in the "Raspberry Pi Compute Module Development Kit" (see [product page](http://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-compute-module)). When I look at the [schematics of the adapter boards](http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-67391/l/raspberry-pi-compute-module-dev-kit--camera-display-adapter-schematic) they seem to only connect the two different cables together... but even if there was some circuity, why didn't they incorporate the adapters into the IO board themselves and save people from extra HW hassle with those adapters?

It seems the only reason could be to save space with smaller connectors for the thinner cables and thus make the (already expensive) IO board a very little bit cheaper... but then again, you have to pay for the separate adapters which really does not make a lot of sense to me.

While this answer may provoke answers with an opinion bias I am interested in trying to find a reason that would make at least a bit of sense.

Comment: It may allow them to update the compute module to swap out the compute module without changing the accessory connections. Keeping the cost of upgrades cheaper.

Comment: I am talking about the IO board and not about the compute module itself... it really seems the reason was to fit all the smaller CSI and DSI connectors to the io board into a single row (they take up one whole side with HDMI connector).

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question, one can only guess and make suppositions.